# Can i get Xpath from UIAutomator Viewer in Appium?

Tags: android, automation, appium, uiautomatorviewer

How can i get Xpath or css path from UIAutomator Viewer, am testing android app in my case there is no id,name. It's showing only the index and classname.

Comment: on which os you are doing android app development

Comment: Am using it in Windows

Comment: just check out this link it will definitely help you http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html

Comment: Thank you..It was helpfull.